How to replace my local branch with master after merge on github.com
This might have been asked earlier, but I could not find a definite answer.
These are the steps done so far.

Checkout 'master' on my local. Create a feature branch 'abc' on my IntelliJ.
Changed some code, commit and push.
Open a Pull Request on Github.com [web]
Run 'Squash & Merge' on Github.com.
Branch 'abc' is now merged into 'master' and deleted.
My local code still points to branch 'abc' [which does not exist on remote/internet]

How do I replace or re-point my local code to 'master' from 'abc' ? I don't want to delete and checkout every time.

you need to fetch so that you can sync with what the remote has.... then you need to pull into your local master so that it gets what is in the remote... you will need to remove the local branch abc if you deem it necessary.

»Branch 'abc' is now merged into 'master' and deleted.« – no, the branch was not merged; it was squashed. A squash is not a merge. Best to stop using this terminology now.

@knittl, its not my terminology. Github prints in the PR that " deleted the 'abc' branch last week." [This is after the Squash & merge happens]

@RijuMahna yes, "the branch was deleted" is fine (that's what actually happened). "Squash & merge" doesn't exist. Either you merge or you squash. A squash(-merge) is not a merge. It's really unfortunate that the word "merge" was chosen here, when it is completely different from a real merge.



Run 'Squash & Merge' on Github.com.


Stop doing that. Despite Github's false claim it is not a merge and creates all kinds of problems. Do yourself and the rest of the world a favour and use normal, proper merges.
